# iterating matching and merging datas

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, csv, hash

I have two csv files named

**alexa_products.csv**

```
name,         sku,      urle,     product,  data

amazon,   amazon.com,   current,  mobile,   seller

vinnes,   vinnes.com,   current,  cellular, Aircel_Indore
```

**Data.csv**

```
name,          sku,      urle,    product,   data

linkedin.com, linkeidn,  current, local,     blah

airtel.com,    airtel,   current, sim,       Airtel

amazon.com,    amazon,   face, network,    buyier

vinnes.com,    vinnes,   look, hands,      ddde
```

Now i have to match name from file1 and sku from file2 if there is any match and i have to print out only the particular column in another csv file

Comment: Welcome to SO. Usually people come here to ask a question. Something of the kind : "here is my problem; I have tried X, but instead of getting Y, I am getting Z. Where did I go wrong?" . Can you improve your post to become such a question?

Comment: Do you specifically need a `perl` answer, or are you willing to accept others? You tagged the question `perl` but are showing no attempt at writing any `perl` script yourself...

Comment: @Floris i want the answer in perl

Comment: @user3231692 - you need to attempt to solve this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are waiting for someone to give you the `perl` solution, here is the `awk` one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}FNR==NR{if(NR>1){a[$2]=$2;next}}($2 in a){print $0}' alexa_products.csv Data.csv
```

Explanation:

```
BEGIN     - do this before anything else
FS=","    - set "field separator" to comma
FNR==NR   - do this if the total number of records == records in this file;
            this means you are processing the first file
if(NR>1)  - skip the first line (or you will get "sku" to match "ski")
a[$2]=$2; - create an array a with value = key = field 2 (the sku column)
($2 in a) - processing the second file : is the sku found in the array
print $0  - if so, print the whole line
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I dont want only the amazon and vines but i want the entire row data of the matched column

Comment: Well that is a strange interpretation of " i have to print out only the particular column in another csv file". Just change the last `$2` to a `$0` to print the entire row

Comment: i have updated the question please see the edits....I have data difference...now if any match found i have to print out datas from both the file into another file?..

Answer (score 0):

1. Hash the values of the given column from the smaller file.
2. Process the larger file,
3. if the value in the given column exists as a key in the hash, output it.

Use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) to process CSV data.